# Clearing .NET Cache for Sitecore

Tags: c#, .net, sitecore

I need to clear a Cache which is being used for a custom module in Sitecore, what's the best practice to clear it?

We're currently adding keys to the cache with

```
System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Cache.Add(key, obj, dependencyKey, DatTime.MaxValue);
```

This cache does not get cleared out on publish though and I need to clear it manually. I know it is possible to hook into Sitecores publish event, but need a way to clear it.

Tried removing keys with:

```
System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Cache.Remove(key);
```

But it did not do the trick

Comment: Is your question on how to trigger your code at the end of a publish, or why .Remove() is not clearing the cache?

Comment: The question is to why .Remove() is not removing it on the frontend

Comment: "On the frontend" - did you add your code to publish:end or publish:end:remote event?

Comment: It has been added to both. Do I need to somehow make a for loop and delete every key in the cache or is there some kind of cache.clear() im missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no `.Clear()` method.

You can iterate over all the entries and remove them by their key (or ID), using the `GetEnumerator` method of the `Cache` class.

```
IDictionaryEnumerator enumerator = Cache.GetEnumerator();
while(enumerator.MoveNext()) 
{
    Cache.Remove(enumerator.Key); 
}
```

I would run this code in a publish:end:remote event.

Comment: Wouldn't this code result in an `InvalidOperationException` because you're modifying a collection while enumerating it? Having `.GetEnumerator`, wouldn't it be better to use `foreach` (and thus be able to copy the data via `.ToArray()`)?

Comment: Yeah read somewhere that it would (or could) cause a lot of problems. How about setting a slidingexpiration and then adding a new key on publish? Would that clear cache as well?

Comment: That would (eventually) clear cache, but that seems to be over-complicating your code with a lot of key management. As far as the enumerator problem: what Aravol suggests might happen. I'm not sure. The enumerator is a separately instantiated object that is created before the cache object is modified. Since we are moving always forward through the cache, I think it's safe. If not, the iteration code could be made more robust. Regardless, I would still clear the cache in this manner and do it on publish:end:remote event.